# function(SELECT x, y ...) doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, I am trying to make a query less verbose. Instead of

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = Point(
    If(
        condition,
        long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END,
        a different long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END
    ),
    If(
        condition,
        long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END,
        a different long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END
    )
)
```

I tried the following but failed

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = Point(
    SELECT If(condition, x, different(x)), If(condition, y, different(y)) 
    FROM (
        SELECT long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END x, long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END y 
        FROM tbl
    ) foo
)
```

Is it not possible to use a SELECT statement to replace arguments to a function? Or, am I just doing something silly? Or, is there another way to make this `long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` appear only once?

Comment: I would not go as far as calling anything you are doing 'silly', but I suspect MySQL will not let you use a two-column output in such a way that both columns become arguments of the same function the way you are trying to use them. In fact, a subquery in this context is most probably expected to return a *scalar* result, which means a result set with no more than one value (i.e. one column by one row). You might want to elaborate more on what you are doing for me or someone else to be able to come up with a sort of workaround for your problem (or a useful hint).

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
UPDATE tbl AS m_tbl
SET col = (
    SELECT Point( IF(.., x1, x2), 
        IF (.., y1, y2)
    )
    FROM (
        SELECT .. AS x1, 
            .. AS x2, 
            .. AS y1, 
            .. AS y2
        FROM tbl
        WHERE m_tbl.pk_col = tbl.pk_col
    )
)
```

Comment: the above might work, except, the subquery returns all the rows, and UPDATE expects one per row. I tried adding an alias to `tbl` in the UPDATE query, and using the alias to constrain the subquery using the PK, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build your query along the lines of

```
UPDATE tbl
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      tblKey,
      long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END x,
      long CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END y 
    FROM tbl
  ) s ON tbl.tblKey = s.tblKey
SET tbl.col = Point(
  IF(condition, s.x, different(s.x)),
  IF(condition, s.y, different(s.y))
)
```